# What is Spring proxy

Tags: spring, proxy

I know what is Proxy in network community (server intermediary), but what is proxy in Spring ? Why spring beans are wrapped proxy ? I don't understand the idea of proxy in Spring. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy is a Spring generated class, that wraps your class for a given purpose, ie: adding transactional behaviour

Take a deeper look at the documentation [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

It's a class that wraps your class. It is a `proxy` because all calls to methods of your class pass through it before actually getting to your class. The goal is to enhance your class with additional functionality, for example as @CristianMeneses said, to add transactional behavior to it, or inject some resources.

Comment: Ok but which objects are proxy ? I suppose that all Services, Controllers etc are proxy. Am I right ?

Comment: @user3528733 Yes, all Spring beans.